# How can I tell if I have a file-like object?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to have a function that writes data to a file:

```
def data_writer(data, file_name):
    spiffy_data = data # ...
    with open(file_name, 'w') as out:
        out.write(spiffy_data)
```

But sometimes, I have a file object instead of a file name. In this case, I sometimes have a `tempfile.TemporaryFile` (which creates a file-like object that's writable).

I'd like to be able to write something like:

```
def data_writer(data, file_thing):
    spiffy_data = data # ...
    if type(file_thing) is file_like:
        file_thing.write(spiffy_data)
    else:
        with open(file_name, 'w') as out:
            out.write(spiffy_data)
```

What's a good way to do this?

Also, does makes sense to do in Python?

Comment: I'd just check whether you got a string with `isinstance(file_thing, str)`.  If so, treat it as a filename, otherwise treat it as a file-like object.

Comment: Why not always take a file-like and let the caller handle it?

Comment: Alternatively, some APIs ([e.g. `tarfile.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.open)) take a file name by default, but allow you to pass a `fileobj` instead by keyword so it uses that instead of opening a file. Up to you if this makes sense.

Comment: One possibility instead of checking the `type`, would be to check the attributes of `file_thing` for e.g., `write()`:  `if hasattr(file_thing, 'write'):...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your approach is [`LBYL`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-lbyl), it's pythonic to assume it's [`EAFP`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp). So you could just `try` to

- `write()` to the `file_thing` you received or
- `open()` it

and `except` a potential exception, depending on which you feel better represents the default case.

**Edit:** Cf [ShadowRanger's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40110731/how-can-i-tell-if-i-have-a-file-like-object/40110875#comment67493524_40110875) for why mixing the exception handling with a context manager is rather unelegant here.

Comment: EAFP doesn't work so well here; by the time you try to `write`, you're already in the writing logic, and it's awkward to retroactively open the file. Particularly if you're being good and using `with` statements to manage the lifetime of a file object you open.

Comment: Yeah, good point. Handling the exception doesn't mix great with the context manager :/

Comment: I think if the writing logic is factored out (or is actually a one-liner) then it's OK. You do have to copy/paste the call to write data, which is ugly, but I'm not seeing a solution there...

Answer (score 3):

A function should do one thing, and do that one thing well. In the case of `data_writer`, its one thing is to write data to a file-like object. Let the caller worry about providing such an object. That said, you can also provide that caller in the form of a wrapper that takes a file name and opens it for `data_writer`.

```
def data_writer(data, file_obj):
    spiffy_data = data # ...
    file_obj.write(spiffy_data)

def write_data_to_file(data, file_name):
    with open(file_name, "w") as f:
        data_writer(f, file_name)
```